# Opening VS 2010 projects to VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2019

After opening vs2010(4.0 framework client) project in vs2019(4.72 framework) I got these error. The form designers cannot open as form designer window. Please help me. Im new with VS2019 thank you.

ERROR: Could not resolve COM reference "6ae44ff1-eccf-4a72-96ce-95bcd1ea2097" version 13.0. The type library importer encountered an error during type verification. Try importing without class members.   MAFDC

Answer (score 0):

go to solution explorer and open reference and  then look for REPORTLIB "or something close to this " it will be highlighted with yellow color and remove it from your project reference.

I hope this work for you.